# Data Augmentation techniques for classification of imbalanced time series datasets

Tags: classification, time-series, class-imbalance, data-augmentation

Now I have a task to classify the imbalanced time series datasets using ML classifiers, such as Logistic Regression, Decision Tree, SVM, and KNN. I am not allowed to use the Deep Learning tools, such as CNN and RNN. The time series data is measurements of the Force-Displacement Curve from a production line. The dataset is extremely imbalanced (minority class: majority class= 1:100). So I want to use Data Augmentation techniques to enlarge the size of the minority class, in order to optimize the performance of the classifiers and avoid overfitting.

I have tried many tools in feature-space, such as oversampling, undersampling, SMOTE, ADASYN and so on. But their performance is not so perfect. And I wish to generate synthetic time series data using Data Augmentation techniques, based on the initial data.
Similar to Image Recognition, I have also tried the exiting methods which have been applied to images, such as scaling, rotation, and jittering. But they are also not so useful.

So I want to ask if there are any other DA techniques to generate synthetic time series data. I have only some initial ideas, such as using DTW, Fournier Transform, Markov Chain and so on, but no papers or code about applying them.

Can anyone help me? I really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: I think it might be hard to augment time-series data.  Have you considered re-weighting your training samples as a strategy to overcome the class imbalance?  Re-weighting would probably be easier than DA in this scenario

Comment: @zachdj Thank you zachdj for your comment. But my task is to augment the time series dataset. The optimization in algorithm-level or resampling strategies I have already tried, but they are not my demand. I only want to know how to generate synthetic time series data, namely curves, but preserving the labels and important information and features of initial dataset.

Comment: In that case, this cross-validated post might be helpful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/320952/data-augmentation-strategies-for-time-series-forecasting

Comment: The strategies in that post are for forecasting, but some of them may work for your classification problem as well.